# QRCode scanning issue

Tags: iphone, ios, qr-code, zxing

I am using Zxing SDK for scanning(decoding) QRCodes, it works well, but it does not scan some QRCode especially for smaller size QRCodes.

Any help?

Comment: Could you explain `smaller sie QRCodes` ..How small are they interms of size i mean.

Comment: i don't know the exact size and i am not sure that the cause of issue is the QRCode sie actaully i tried with 2 QR's one is scanned perfectly but the aother one is not detected

Comment: You can try to increase contrast of the image before resolving the QR code (the most extreme contrast is converting it to B/W).

Answer (score 0):

add these types of codes to the scanning class , it will support all types of codes. **let supportedCodeTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]**